# FaceTime application not available

Tags: iphone, facetime

I bought my iPhone 6 Plus in Georgia. I am using the phone in Georgia. FaceTime is not available on my iPhone. Please tell me how to get it to work.

Comment: lol @Buscar웃 ... may be you can take a break :D FaceTime is something totally different from Facebook

Answer (score 3):

You should check with your service provider to see if FaceTime is supported.

From [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204168):

> You might have issues using FaceTime for one of these reasons:
>
> - **FaceTime Audio or Video calling might not be available for all countries, regions, or carriers.**
> - FaceTime isn't available or might not appear on devices purchased in Saudi Arabia, United Arab Emirates, and Pakistan.
> - Call forwarding isn't supported by FaceTime.
> - Phone calls end when switching to or answering a FaceTime call.
> - You can't switch from a FaceTime call to a voice call, or from a FaceTime Video call to a FaceTime Audio call.